# Performance issue with "new ReportDocument()"

Tags: c#, .net, performance, crystal-reports

I have a C# application where I create a Crystal Reports ReportDocument, with the line

`CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument document =
                        new CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument();`

This line takes 3-4 seconds to execute. This seems very slow, especially since the

`document.Load(file)`

line following it (which actually does the major part of the work of reading in a report file and creating the report's object model) executes extremely quickly.

What are things I should keep in mind that might improve performance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to https://www.sdn.sap.com/irj/sdn/message?messageID=5898122 3-4 seconds fór this constructor call is "quite normal".